# Create dynamic averages

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider this example table:

[image: Data table]

A sensor gives me measurements even now and then. But I need them in a regular interval, so I am aiming to get a running average:

[image: Average table]

When I say, *at `time=5` (A1) I want the average of the sensor values for the last 5 seconds*, I clearly have to calculate the average of the sensor values that have a time (A) value `>=5-5` and `<=5`. I for myself can calculate that, but what would I have to write into D2 to automate it?

It would be a *Calculate the average of the cells `A2:B10` on page 1 where the A cell is smaller or equal C2 and larger or equal B2; take the value of the B cell*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `SUMPRODUCT` function to find the total with conditions.

For data on Sheet1 (your first example table) and the averages on Sheet2, you can use this formula to find the average for all the sensorvalues in the five second interval ending at the time in A2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2-Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10<5)*(A2-Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10>=0)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10))/SUMPRODUCT((A2-Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10<5)*(A2-Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10>=0))
```

The first `SUMPRODUCT` function finds the sum of the sensor values that fall in the desired time interval. The second `SUMPRODUCT` function (the divisor) finds the number of data points that fall in the time interval.

For the data you posted:
[image]

Comment: This is great! :-)